# Cache not working in GitHub Actions workflow

Tags: github-actions

I want to speed up npm install by using locally cached modules instead of downloading them each time.

I have a very simple minimal example of a GitHub Actions workflow that implements an npm module cache. Only two files, `package.json` and the workflow YAML file.

However the cache isn’t being used during npm installs.

I want to have separate save and restore steps rather than use the setup-node cache feature.

Here’s the `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "workflow-npm-dependency-cache",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Minimal example of a workflow npm cache",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "echo Building...",
    "test": "echo Testing...",
    "deploy": "echo Deploying..."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "debug": "^4.2.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "marked": "^4.2.4",
    "highlight.js": "^11.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.3.6",
    "chance": "^1.1.8",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.12",
    "mocha": "^10.0.0",
    "sinon": "^14.0.0"
  }
}
```

Here’s the workflow (`.github/workflows/buildAndDeploy.yml`):

```yaml
name: Build
on:
  push:
    branches: 
      - main
      - fix-*
      - feature-*
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  nodejs_version: ${{ github.event.inputs.nodejs_version || '20.4.0' }}
  repo_dir: repo
  cache_name: npm-modules-cache 
 
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Clone Deploy Repository (Latest)
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          path: ${{ env.repo_dir }}
 
      - name: Setup NodeJS
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ env.nodejs_version }}

      - name: List node modules (1)
        continue-on-error: true
        run: cd $repo_dir && npm list

      - name: Restore npm module cache
        uses: actions/cache/restore@v3
        id: cache-npm-restore
        with:
          path: ~/.npm
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache_name }}
          
      - name: List node modules (2)
        if: ${{ steps.cache-npm-restore.outputs.cache-hit == 'true' }}
        continue-on-error: true
        run: cd $repo_dir && npm list

      - name: Install NodeJS modules
        run: | 
          cd $repo_dir && npm install
 
      - name: Save npm module cache
        if: ${{ steps.cache-npm-restore.outputs.cache-hit != 'true' }}
        uses: actions/cache/save@v3
        id: cache-npm-save
        with:
          path: ~/.npm
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache_name }}

      - name: List node modules (3)
        if: ${{ steps.cache-npm-restore.outputs.cache-hit != 'true' }}
        continue-on-error: true
        run: cd $repo_dir && npm list
 
      - name: Build
        run: |
          cd $repo_dir && npm run build
          
      - name: Test
        run: |
          cd $repo_dir && npm run test
      
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
  
    steps:
      - name: Clone Deploy Repository (Latest)
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          path: ${{ env.repo_dir }}

      - name: List node modules (4)
        continue-on-error: true
        run: cd $repo_dir && npm list
          
      - name: Restore npm module cache
        uses: actions/cache/restore@v3
        with:
          path: ~/.npm
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-build-${{ env.cache_name }}
 
      - name: List node modules (5)
        continue-on-error: true
        run: cd $repo_dir && npm list

      - name: Install NodeJS modules
        run: | 
          cd $repo_dir && npm install
          
      - name: Build
        run: |
          cd $repo_dir && npm run deploy
```

When run the build job successfully creates a cache, and the deploy job successfully restores the cache, however the deploy job "List node modules (5)" step shows that none of the modules are present, and so the npm install command doesn’t install using the cache:

```
Run cd $repo_dir && npm list
npm ERR! code ELSPROBLEMS
npm ERR! missing: chai@^4.3.6, required by workflow-npm-dependency-cache@0.0.1
npm ERR! missing: chance@^1.1.8, required by workflow-npm-dependency-cache@0.0.1
npm ERR! missing: cheerio@^1.0.0-rc.12, required by workflow-npm-dependency-cache@0.0.1
npm ERR! missing: debug@^4.2.0, required by workflow-npm-dependency-cache@0.0.1
npm ERR! missing: ejs@^3.1.6, required by workflow-npm-dependency-cache@0.0.1
npm ERR! missing: highlight.js@^11.7.0, required by workflow-npm-dependency-cache@0.0.1
npm ERR! missing: marked@^4.2.4, required by workflow-npm-dependency-cache@0.0.1
npm ERR! missing: mocha@^10.0.0, required by workflow-npm-dependency-cache@0.0.1
npm ERR! missing: sinon@^14.0.0, required by workflow-npm-dependency-cache@0.0.1
workflow-npm-dependency-cache@0.0.1 /home/runner/work/workflow-npm-dependency-cache/workflow-npm-dependency-cache/repo
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY chai@^4.3.6
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY chance@^1.1.8
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY cheerio@^1.0.0-rc.12
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY debug@^4.2.0
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY ejs@^3.1.6
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY highlight.js@^11.7.0
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY marked@^4.2.4
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY mocha@^10.0.0
└── UNMET DEPENDENCY sinon@^14.0.0
```

Even though the deploy job "Restore npm module cache" worked:

```
Run actions/cache/restore@v3
Received 195 of 195 (100.0%), 0.0 MBs/sec
Cache Size: ~0 MB (195 B)
/usr/bin/tar -xf /home/runner/work/_temp/b7061dc5-d9d8-46a8-84c4-8ac40b635d39/cache.tzst -P -C /home/runner/work/workflow-npm-dependency-cache/workflow-npm-dependency-cache --use-compress-program unzstd
Cache restored successfully
Cache restored from key: Linux-build-npm-modules-cache
```

Why doesn't the cache get used during the deploy job npm install?

Comment: By "List node modules (5)" you've restored the cache to `~/.npm` but **not** actually installed it to `./node_modules`, so it's unclear why you expected a different outcome.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks - perhaps I have a misunderstanding of how npm list works. I saw it used in other peoples workflows. I assumed (perhaps incorrectly) that it was being used to check which modules were in the cache. How do I verify that the modules got installed from local cache? (Aside from just seeing that I the install is much faster)

Comment: FYI - in my real non minimal example workflow the install time (approx 3-4 mins) is the same with the cache steps as it is without them. So I’m assuming the cache isn’t being used.